# Cross-Domain Cookies

Tags: cookies, web-applications, cross-domain

I have two webapps WebApp1 and WebApp2 in two different domains.

1. I am setting a cookie in WebApp1 in the HttpResponse.
2. How to read the same cookie from HttpRequest in WebApp2?

I know it sounds weird because cookies are specific to a given domain, and we can't access them from different domains; I've however heard of CROSS-DOMAIN cookies which can be shared across multiple  webapps. How to implement this requirement using CROSS-DOMAIN cookies?

Note: I am trying this with J2EE webapps

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests if it helps

Answer (score 181):

Yes, it is absolutely possible to get the cookie from `domain1.example` by `domain2.example`. I had the same problem for a social plugin of my social network, and after a day of research I found the solution.

First, on the server side you need to have the following headers:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://origin.domain:port");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *");
```

Within the PHP-file you can use `$_COOKIE[name]`

Second, on the client side:

Within your AJAX request you need to include 2 parameters

```
crossDomain: true
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
```

Example:

```
type: "get",
url: link,
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'json',
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
}
```

Comment: Or if you are not wanting to filter on origin, just use $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] instead of *

Comment: This is the only things that worked for me. Also, * was not accepted as origin, so @Joel Teply's tip is needed.

Comment: It worked perfectly when I run the code on localhost, but at runtime I don't see the cookies being set to the API and I get a 401 (unauthorized) error as expected. any ideas?

Comment: This won't work if third-party cookies are disabled (automatic for some browser situations). See https://blog.zok.pw/web/2015/10/21/3rd-party-cookies-in-practice/ and http://www.allannienhuis.com/archives/2013/11/03/blocked-3rd-party-session-cookies-in-iframes/ for more information.

Comment: Don't use Joel's tip, because it is "in essence" the same as setting it to "*" which can open up subtle security holes so is discouraged, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-are-the-security-risks-of-setting-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: on the server side of which domain?

Comment: somebody please accept this as a valid answer! It answers the question but it is not complete. It also needs to mention that the cookie has to have `SameSite:none; secure` like stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63728389/985942

Comment: There is no `crossDomain` field in [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: @belkka I guess the answer assumes [`jQuery`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: It looks like in order to make it work from localhost the credentials value is not enough, maybe also you need to set up `SameSite:none;` in your server

Comment: This answer works but has no explanation what's going on, and explaining "domain2.com can **get** the cookie from domain1.com" is incorrect (for example JavaScript cannot get the cookie value). See the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/63728389/5267751 for better explanation.

Answer (score 153):

As other people say, you cannot share cookies, but you could do something like this:

1. centralize all cookies in a single domain, let's say `cookiemaker.example`
2. when the user makes a request to `example.com` you redirect him to `cookiemaker.example`
3. `cookiemaker.example` redirects him back to `example.com` with the information you need

Of course, it's not completely secure, and you have to create some kind of internal protocol between your apps to do that.

Lastly, it would be very annoying for the user if you do something like that in every request, but not if it's just the first.

But I think there is no other way.

Comment: If there is no other way, then how does StackExchange/OpenID work?

Comment: @Hawken StackExchange/OpenID follows the same process as described above. You are directed to a different site (SO > SX), confirm your identity, and then are directed back to SO with the information you need. [The OpenID Spec](http://openid.net/developers/specs/) explains more, although [Wikipedia does it more plainly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#Logging_in).

Comment: @alcuadrado How can you identify different users with this solution? Let say a user from a.com logged in and you set the information needed. Now when user go to b.com that uses same same script/application/plug-in how will you know that is the same user?

Comment: All users are logged in in cookiemaker.com actually. And it redirects the user to the different sites with a special and secure message that verifies that they are logged in and who they are. How to implement it is up to you, there are infinite ways of doing so. Maybe you can use this: http://jwt.io/

Comment: @nickq This isn't unique to OpenID, SAML2 implementations conceptually work in pretty much  the same way.

Comment: @Andrew_1510 `cookiebaker` would be better ;-)

Comment: @alcuadrado, could you please explain a bit more detailed: 1) how cookiemaker knows where to redirect user after he is authenticated? Should origin-url come in querystring? 2) How "information you need" is passed to example.com while redirecting to it at step 3?

Comment: Both have almost the same answer. 1) You redirect to something like cookimaker.com?redirection=yoursite.com 2) also as a query string parameter

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19546680/2218697) is post with image tag , is that a **better solution** ?

Comment: @Sasha If it's not too late (I bet it is), you should look into OpenID Connect

Answer (score 84):

As far as I know, cookies are limited by the "same origin" policy. However, with CORS you can receive and use the "Server B" cookies to establish a persistent session from "Server A" on "Server B".

Although, this requires some headers on "Server B":

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://server-a.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

And you will need to send the flag "**withCredentials**" on all the "Server A" requests (ex: `xhr.withCredentials = true;`)

You can read about it here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: This wont work for some users because CORS cookies will not work if third-party cookies are disabled e.g. [Safari by default](http://blog.prowebsoftware.net/2013/08/safari-cors-requests-withcredentials/) e.g. [Mozilla settings](http://www.goeszen.com/how-to-get-cookies-working-with-cors-jquery-and-xhr-ajax.html). Google [more examples](https://www.google.com/#q=withCredentials+third-party-cookies) and an [article about why Facebook](http://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2010/08/how-facebook-sets-and-uses-cross-domain-cookies/) doesn't use third party cookies.

Comment: Does stack exchange / openID use CORS?

Comment: FWIW I just tested a normal CORS withCredentials XHR and it worked on FF/Safari/Chrome...though I wouldn't doubt that facebook/google use more sophisticated schemes

Comment: Is this a full solution for sharing an auth cookie between domain1.com and domain2.com?  If so why do other posts say this is impossible?

Answer (score 62):

There's no such thing as cross domain cookies. You could share a cookie between `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` but never between `example.com` and `example2.com` and that's for security reasons.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, can u please add more clarity on configuration part, how to create/configure domain and subdomain in j2ee environment???

Comment: This is a question that is more adapted to http://serverfault.com where you will get answers from experts in the domain.

Comment: Hi, 
I tried having two webapps 
WebApp.domain.com ==> here i add cookie in respose as follows:
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("namedCookie","test");
cookie.setDomain(".domain.com");
response.addCookie(cookie);

WebApp1.domain.com==>Here i tried to access the cookie as follows, but cant able to access

Cookie[]cks = request.getCookies();
for(int i=0;i<cks.length;i++){
out.print("cookie found"+cks[i].getValue());
}

Any idea on this?

Comment: often repeated but not true, see my answer below or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186645/cross-domain-cookies-a-maybe-new-idea

Comment: Yes there is. You just need to use CORS.

Comment: How to  share cookies between `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19546680/2218697) is post with image tag , is that a **better solution** for asp mvc ?

Comment: "never" here is a bit misleading since you can access through CORS and "use 2 cookies" at the same time on the same page, as it were...which is almost like sharing them :)

Comment: @JeffTian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain here is explanation

Comment: False, you can... by token, that will store the cross-domain cookie.

Answer (score 54):

The smartest solution is to follow facebook's path on this. How does facebook know who you are when you visit any domain? It's actually very [simple](http://dorianroy.com/blog/2010/04/how-facebooks-like-button-works/):

The Like button actually allows Facebook to track all visitors of the external site, no matter if they click it or not. Facebook can do that because they use an **iframe** to display the button. An iframe is something like an embedded browser window within a page. The difference between using an iframe and a simple image for the button is that the *iframe contains a complete web page – from Facebook*. There is not much going on on this page, except for the button and the information about how many people have liked the current page.

So when you see a like button on cnn.com, you are actually visiting a Facebook page at the same time. That allows Facebook to read a cookie on your computer, which it has created the last time you’ve logged in to Facebook.

A fundamental security rule in every browser is that only the website that has created a cookie can read it later on. And that is the advantage of the iframe: it allows Facebook to read your Facebook-cookie even when you are visiting a different website. That’s how they recognize you on cnn.com and display your friends there.

Source:

- http://dorianroy.com/blog/2010/04/how-facebooks-like-button-works/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8256920/715483

Comment: I think an iframe would rarely classify as the best or the smartest way to do anything.. but it is the easiest.

Comment: Wouldn't the cookie from facebook be recognized as a third party cookie?!

Comment: Facebook domain will not have access to the parent window cookies, the most it can get is `window.parent.location` if they want, but it really doesn't matter because the parent window consciously choose to add the facebook-iframe, it means that on loading-time facebook already knows the parent page identifier. Basically, the parent page wants the facebook track-ability function. On the user side, to block it, it is needed some browser-extension to block undesired domains, like uBlock origin for Chrome.

Answer (score 50):

Cross-domain cookies **are not allowed** (i.e. site A cannot set a cookie on site B).

*But once a cookie is set by site A*, you can send that cookie even in **requests from site B to site A** [(i.e. cross-domain requests)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials):

> `XMLHttpRequest` from a different domain **cannot set cookie values for their own domain unless `withCredentials` is set to true** before making the request. The third-party cookies obtained by setting `withCredentials` to true **will still honor same-origin policy** and hence **can not** be accessed by the requesting script through `document.cookie` or from response headers.

Make sure to do these things:

1. When setting the cookie in a response

   - The `Set-Cookie` **response header** includes `SameSite=None` if the requests are cross-site (note a request from `www.example.dev` to `static.example.dev` is actually a *same-site* request, and can use `SameSite=Strict`)
   - The `Set-Cookie` **response header** should include the `Secure` attribute if served over HTTPS; as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60892766/1175496) and [here](https://digiday.com/media/what-is-chrome-samesite/)
2. When sending/receiving the cookie:

   - The request is made with `withCredentials: true`, as mentioned in other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25861695/1175496) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/1175496), **including the *original request* whose response *sets* the cookie set in the first place**

     - For the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), this attribute is `credentials: 'include'`, vs `withCredentials: true`
     - For [jQuery's ajax method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), note you may need to supply argument `crossDomain: true`
   - The server response includes [cross-origin headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#cors) like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`

     - As @nabrown points out: "Note that the "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`" cannot be the wildcard (`*`) value if you use the `withCredentials: true`" (see @nabrown's comment which explains one workaround for this.
3. In general:

   - Your browser hasn't disabled 3rd-party cookies. (* see below)

Things that you **don't *need*** (just use the above):

1. `domain` attribute in the Set-Cookie; you can choose a root domain (i.e. `a.example.com` can set a cookie with a domain value of `example.com`, but it's not necessary; the cookie will still be sent to `a.example.com`, even if sent from `b.other-site.example.com`
2. For the cookie to be visible in Chrome Dev Tools, "Application" tab; if the value of cookie `HttpOnly` attribute is *true*, Chrome **won't show you the cookie value in the Application tab** (it should show the cookie value when *set* in the initial request, and *sent* in subsequent responses where `withCredentials: true`)

Notice the difference between "path" and "site" for Cookie purposes. "path" is *not* security-related; "site" is security-related:

**path**

Servers can set a `Path` attribute in the `Set-Cookie`, but it doesn't seem security related:

> Note that `path` was intended for performance, *not security*. Web pages having the same origin still can access cookie via `document.cookie` even though the paths are mismatched.

**site**

The SameSite attribute, according to [example.dev article](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/), can restrict or allow cross-site cookies; but what is a "site"?

> It's helpful to understand exactly what 'site' means here. The site is the **combination of the domain suffix and the part of the domain just before it**. For example, the `www.example.dev` domain is part of the `example.dev` site...

This means a request to `static.example.dev` from `www.example.dev`, is a **sameSite** request (the only difference in the URLs is in the **subdomains**).

> The [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/) defines this, so
> it's not just top-level domains like .com but also includes services
> like `github.io`

This means a request to `your-project.github.io` from `my-project.github.io`, is a a **cross-site** request (these URLs are at different domains, because `github.io` is the domain suffix; the domains `your-project` vs `my-project` are different; hence different sites)

This means what's *to the left* of the public suffix; is the subdomain (but the [subdomain is a *part* of the host; see the BONUS reply in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/887183/292784))

- `www` is the subdomain in `www.example.dev`; same site as `static.example.dev`
- `your-project` is the domain in `your-project.github.io`; separate site as `my-project.github.io`

In this URL `https://www.example.com:8888/examples/index.html`, remember these parts:

- the "protocol": `https://`

  - the "scheme": `https`
- the "port": `8888`
- the "domain name" aka [`location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hostname): `www.example.com`

  - the "domain suffix" aka "top-level domain" (TLD): `com`
  - the "domain": `example`
  - the "subdomain": `www` (the subdomain could be single-level (like `www`) or multi-level ([like `foo.bar` in `foo.bar.example.com`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/56985/78688))
- the "site" (as in "cross-site" if another URL had a different "site" value): `example.com`

  - "site" = "domain" + "domain suffix" = `example.com`
- the "path": `/examples/index.html`

Useful links:

- [Anatomy of a URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)
- [Same-Origin cookie policy and URL anatomy](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs261/fa17/scribe/web-security-1.pdf)
- [SameSite cookies explained](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/)
- [Secure cross-domain cookies for HTTP | Journal of Internet Services and Applications | Full Text](https://jisajournal.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/1869-0238-4-13)
- [draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-03](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-03)
- [Web Security 1: Same-Origin and Cookie Policy](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs261/fa17/scribe/web-security-1.pdf)
- [Set-Cookie - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

(*Be careful*; I was testing my feature in  Chrome Incognito tab; according to my `chrome://settings/cookies`; my settings were "Block third party cookies in Incognito", so I can't test Cross-site cookies in Incognito.)

[image: a browser is open to the URL chrome://settings/cookies, which shows that "Block third-party cookies in Incognito" setting is set, choose a setting in your browser that will allow third-party cookies]

Comment: This aren't cross-domain cookies. There is nothing like cross-domain cookies. It's a strict rule you cannot avoid. Page A can never set a cookie for Page B. You're just sending Cookies created by Page B on requests for Page B originating from Page A.

Comment: OK thanks @Sebi2020 I updated the answer I hope I captured the difference

Comment: This answer is clear, thorough and helpful. Note that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" cannot be the wildcard (*) value if you want to use the credentials option (`withCredentials` for XMLHttpRequest, or `credentials` for Fetch API).  [MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials). On the server, you'll have to grab the origin from incoming requests, and return that value in the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. Whether this is a good or bad idea security-wise, I don't know.

Comment: So if the UI app at app1.apps.space.pool.gap.mycompany.net sends a cookie to app2.apps.space.pool.gap.mycompany.net, would that be same-site or cross-site ?

Comment: Hi @copenndthagen , I think that is `same-site` request; both of your URLs are at the same "site" of `mycompany.net`; the same domain and domain suffix. The only difference in your URLs is the subdomain. But that's **still** same site, as in the example: "This means a request to static.example.dev from www.example.dev, is a sameSite request."

Comment: @copenndthagen I think , even though your subdomain is ["multi-level"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/56985/78688), and very long, still the only difference is found in the subdomains: `app1.apps.space.pool.gap` and `app2.apps.space.pool.gap` (remember, `mycompany.net` is the site; consisting of the domain `mycompany` and the domain suffix `net`. Therefore everything "to the left" of `mycompany.next` in your URLs is the subdomain)

Answer (score 20):

You cannot share cookies across domains. You can however allow all subdomains to have access. To allow all subdomains of `example.com` to have access, set the domain to `.example.com`.

It's not possible giving `other.example` access to `example.com`'s cookies though.

Comment: how come `.google.com` cookies show up when browsing to YouTube then?

Comment: Google analytics tags. Those cookies come from google.com, not from youtube.com.

Comment: how do analytics tags fetch cookies from .google.com? I have to set up the same flow in my project.

Answer (score 13):

Do what Google is doing. Create a PHP file that sets the cookie on all 3 domains. Then on the domain where the theme is going to set, create a HTML file that would load the PHP file that sets cookie on the other 2 domains. Example:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <p>Please wait.....</p>
      <img src="http://domain2.example/setcookie.php?theme=whateveryourthemehere" />
      <img src="http://domain3.example/setcookie.php?theme=whateveryourthemehere" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Then add an onload callback on body tag. The document will only load when the images completely load that is when cookies are set on the other 2 domains. Onload Callback:

```
<head>
   <script>
   function loadComplete(){
      window.location="http://domain1.example";//URL of domain1
   }
   </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadComplete()">

setcookie.php
```

We set the cookies on the other domains using a PHP file like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['theme'])){
   setcookie("theme", $_GET['theme'], time()+3600);
}
?>
```

Now cookies are set on the three domains.

Comment: This doesn't work if the 'Block third party cookies' feature is enabled.

Comment: Just a copy-paste of [another answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546680/7710928). There is no "three domains" in this question.

Comment: This won't work on safari either... third party cookies are being deprecated everywhere.

Answer (score 9):

You can attempt to push the cookie val to another domain using an image tag.

Your mileage may vary when trying to do this because some browsers require you to have a proper [P3P Policy](http://www.w3.org/P3P/) on the WebApp2 domain or the browser will reject the cookie.

If you look at plus.google.com p3p policy you will see that their policy is:

CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."

that is the policy they use for their +1 buttons to these cross domain requests.

Another warning is that if you are on https make sure that the image tag is pointing to an https address also otherwise the cookies will not set.

Comment: Care to elaborate a little?

Answer (score 5):

There's a decent overview of [how Facebook does it here on nfriedly.com](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2010/08/how-facebook-sets-and-uses-cross-domain-cookies/)

There's also Browser Fingerprinting, which is not the same as a cookie, but serves a like purpose in that it helps you identify a user with a fair degree of certainty. There's a post [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632995/how-to-gather-info-similar-to-panopticlick-eff-org/9237483#9237483) that references upon one method of fingerprinting

Answer (score 2):

One can use invisible iframes to get the cookies. Let's say there are two domains, `a.example` and `b.example`. For the `index.html` of domain `a.example` one can add  (notice height=0 width=0):

```
<iframe height="0" id="iframe" src="http://b.example" width="0"></iframe>
```

That way your website will get `b.example` cookies assuming that `http://b.example` sets the cookies.

The next thing would be manipulating the site inside the iframe through JavaScript. The operations inside iframe may become a challenge if one doesn't own the second domain. But in case of having access to both domains referring the right web page at the src of iframe should give the cookies one would like to get.

Comment: Just a warning: There are some serious issues with cookies in iframes on Safari. They apparently don't work cross domain.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an NPM module, which allows you to share locally-stored data across domains: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-toss

By using an iframe hosted on Domain A, you can store all of your user data on Domain A, and reference that data by posting requests to the Domain A iframe.

Thus, Domains B, C, etc. can inject the iframe and post requests to it to store and access the desired data.  Domain A becomes the hub for all shared data.

With a domain whitelist inside of Domain A, you can ensure only your dependent sites can access the data on Domain A.

The trick is to have the code inside of the iframe on Domain A which is able to recognize which data is being requested.  The README in the above NPM module goes more in depth into the procedure.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since it is difficult to do 3rd party cookies and also some browsers won't allow that.

You can try storing them in HTML5 local storage and then sending them with every request from your front end app.

Comment: I agree. You can configure everything posted in the answers here, but if [third-party cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#third-party_cookies) are disabled in the browser settings nothing will work. This is a privacy measure to prevent tracking.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetOrder(status, filter) {
    var isValid = true; //isValidGuid(customerId);
    if (isValid) {
        var refundhtmlstr = '';
        //varsURL = ApiPath + '/api/Orders/Customer/' + customerId + '?status=' + status + '&filter=' + filter;
        varsURL = ApiPath + '/api/Orders/Customer?status=' + status + '&filter=' + filter;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            //url: ApiPath + '/api/Orders/Customer/' + customerId + '?status=' + status + '&filter=' + filter,
            url: ApiPath + '/api/Orders/Customer?status=' + status + '&filter=' + filter,
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var htmlStr = '';
                if (data == null || data.Count === 0) {
                    htmlStr = '<div class="card"><div class="card-header">Bu kriterlere uygun sipariş bulunamadı.</div></div>';
                }
                else {
                    $('#ReturnPolicyBtnUrl').attr('href', data.ReturnPolicyBtnUrl);
                    var groupedData = data.OrderDto.sort(function (x, y) {
                        return new Date(y.OrderDate) - new Date(x.OrderDate);
                    });
                    groupedData = _.groupBy(data.OrderDto, function (d) { return toMonthStr(d.OrderDate) });
                    localStorage['orderData'] = JSON.stringify(data.OrderDto);

                    $.each(groupedData, function (key, val) {

                        var sortedData = groupedData[key].sort(function (x, y) {
                            return new Date(y.OrderDate) - new Date(x.OrderDate);
                        });
                        htmlStr += '<div class="card-header">' + key + '</div>';
                        $.each(sortedData, function (keyitem, valitem) {
                            //Date Convertions
                            if (valitem.StatusDesc != null) {
                                valitem.StatusDesc = valitem.StatusDesc;
                            }

                            var date = valitem.OrderDate;
                            date = date.substring(0, 10).split('-');
                            date = date[2] + '.' + date[1] + '.' + date[0];
                            htmlStr += '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 card-item clearfix ">' +
                        //'<div class="card-item-head"><span class="order-head">Sipariş No: <a href="ViewOrderDetails.html?CustomerId=' + customerId + '&OrderNo=' + valitem.OrderNumber + '" >' + valitem.OrderNumber + '</a></span><span class="order-date">' + date + '</span></div>' +
                        '<div class="card-item-head"><span class="order-head">Sipariş No: <a href="ViewOrderDetails.html?OrderNo=' + valitem.OrderNumber + '" >' + valitem.OrderNumber + '</a></span><span class="order-date">' + date + '</span></div>' +
                        '<div class="card-item-head-desc">' + valitem.StatusDesc + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="card-item-body">' +
                            '<div class="slider responsive">';
                            var i = 0;
                            $.each(valitem.ItemList, function (keylineitem, vallineitem) {
                                var imageUrl = vallineitem.ProductImageUrl.replace('{size}', 200);
                                htmlStr += '<div><img src="' + imageUrl + '" alt="' + vallineitem.ProductName + '"><span class="img-desc">' + ProductNameStr(vallineitem.ProductName) + '</span></div>';
                                i++;
                            });
                            htmlStr += '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                        });
                    });

                    $.each(data.OrderDto, function (key, value) {
                        if (value.IsSAPMigrationflag === true) {
                            refundhtmlstr = '<div class="notify-reason"><span class="note"><B>Notification : </B> Geçmiş siparişleriniz yükleniyor.  Lütfen kısa bir süre sonra tekrar kontrol ediniz. Teşekkürler. </span></div>';
                        }
                    });
                }
                $('#orders').html(htmlStr);
                $("#notification").html(refundhtmlstr);
                ApplySlide();
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("System Failure");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Web.config

Include UI origin and set Allow Credentials to true

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://burada.com" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with @Ludovic(approved answer) answers we need to check one more option when getting set-cookies header,

```
set-cookie: SESSIONID=60B2E91C53B976B444144063; Path=/dev/api/abc; HttpOnly
```

Check for **Path** attribute value also. This should be the same as your API starting context path like below

```
https://www.example.com/dev/api/abc/v1/users/123
```

or use below value when not sure about context path

```
Path=/;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Three main kinds of browser-based storage**:

1. session storage
2. local storage
3. cookie storage

---

- **Secure cookies** - are used by encrypted websites to offer protection from any possible threats from a hacker.
- **access cookie** - `document.cookie`. This means that this cookie is exposed and can be exploited through cross-site scripting. The saved cookie values can be seen through the browser console.

> As a precaution, you should always try to make your cookies inaccessible on the client-side using JavaScript.

- **HTTPonly** - ensures that a cookie is not accessible using the JavaScript code. This is the most crucial form of protection against cross-scripting attacks.
- **A secure attribute** - ensures that the browser will reject cookies unless the connection happens over HTTPS.
- **sameSite** attribute improves cookie security and avoids privacy leaks.
- **sameSite=Lax** - It is set to Lax (sameSite = Lax) meaning a cookie is only set when the domain in the URL of the browser matches the domain of the cookie, thus eliminating third party’s domains. This will restrict cross-site sharing even between different domains that the same publisher owns. we need to include SameSite=None to avoid the new default of Lax:

> Note: There is a draft spec that requires that the Secure attribute be set to true when the SameSite attribute has been set to 'none'. Some web browsers or other clients may be adopting this specification.

- Using includes as `{ withCredentials: true }` must include all the cookies with the request from the front end.

```
const data = { email: 'youremailaddress@gmail.com' , password: '1234' };
const response = await axios.post('www.yourapi.com/login', data , { withCredentials: true });
```

- Cookie should only be accepted over a secure HTTPS connection. In order to get this to work, we must move the web application to HTTPS.

#### In express.js

```
res.cookie('token', token, {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // would expire after (for 15 minutes  1000 * 60 * 15 ) 15 minutes
      httpOnly: true, // The cookie only accessible by the web server
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true, // Marks the cookie to be used with HTTPS only.
    });
```

[Reference 1](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/what-are-cookies-nodejs/), [Reference 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5330276/Cross-Domain-Embedding-Making-Third-Party-Cookies)

Answer (score -4):

Read `Cookie`  in `Web Api`

```
var cookie = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("newhbsslv1");


                    Logger.Log("Cookie  " + cookie, LoggerLevel.Info);
                    Logger.Log("Cookie count  " + cookie.Count, LoggerLevel.Info);

                    if (cookie != null && cookie.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Logger.Log("Befor For  " , LoggerLevel.Info);
                        foreach (var perCookie in cookie[0].Cookies)
                        {
                            Logger.Log("perCookie  " + perCookie, LoggerLevel.Info);

                            if (perCookie.Name == "newhbsslv1")
                            {
                                strToken = perCookie.Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This does not handle the OP question of using on two different domains